# Default branch changes while importing repository in Azure Devops Repos

Tags: git, azure-devops

When I try to import a repo from one organization to another in my azure devops, the repo successfully gets imported but the default branch of the repo which was 'main' gets automatically changed to some other branch.

```
az repos import create --git-source-url sourceUrl  --org "https://dev.azure.com/testOrg0206"  --project $Project_Name --repository $Repo_Name --requires-authorization
```

This is the command I have used to import repositories.

This is the default branch in my primary repository:
[image: This is the default branch in my primary repository]

This is what I get after importing:
[image: This is what I get after importing.]

Please do let me know what could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it is happening but you can set default branch after importing using this command

```
az repos update --org "https://dev.azure.com/testOrg0206" --project $Project_Name --repository $Repo_Name --default-branch "main"
```